# React setState slow

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, setstate

so I was programming an app with React and what happened is that I have a component with a fairly large list in its state. I am fetching a JSON file from network and then storing a filtered copy directly to component's state. Might be unoptimal solution BUT I think that's still okay and React should handle it I mean, it's just 10 kB.

Anyway I decided to add a search input to my component and store its value to its state. Now I have both the large list and searchInput in its state which I am setStating every onChange and filtering the list based on that.

And that is super slow. Every setState is refreshing the list and doing componentUpdates on every children and subchildren of the component which basically makes the search unusable.

So my question is how to fix this issue? Should I store the filtered list in the redux store instead of local component state? That doesn't seem that good a solution either as I have now a global searchInput value which I have to reset and delete on leave and which I think is better as local value.

Here's how it's currently:

`list -> component -> filter list -> child -> split the list into 4 -> subchild -> map the sublist -> render the list item values`

What I thought too was adding additional list with values showing which items should be hidden/shown so instead of manipulating the large list I am manipulating smaller list of item ids. Still that seems a bit silly, this thing shouldn't be this hard I mean people have been doing lists with JS and HTML quite a while now. I was thinking about re-creating the same component with Vue just to see would it be better (which I think it would).

Comment: You could paginate the network response's results

Comment: @Héctor what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of work with, say, 5000 items at the same time, you could fetch the first 100 ones (for example), and include in your webapp some kind of pagination. So, in your state, there are just 100 items simultaneously and your filtering will be much faster

Comment: The biggest performance hit probably comes when you render the list item values. You should consider only rendering the elements that will actually be in view with some sort of infinite scrolling as you go down. I think there is a package called `react-list` that does this.

Comment: @JoeClay yep the original data is inside Redux reducer. And the list isn't actually that long, only 160 with some nested properties which is why this thing seemed so silly to me. I just to want to move on to more important things. If it helps and no one can come with a clear solution in couple days I'll make a code snippet or just link to the repo so anyone can see it for themselves.

Comment: Use a debounce pattern for search and react-virtualized for list rendering. This is a common problem and when the constraints of the project is "load all items" is the best way to handle it.

Comment: Don't copy Redux state into your component state - filter it directly in your render method (which will get run every time new props are sent in), or potentially use [selectors](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html).

Answer (score 4):

I see your problem. It's not actually the setState that is slow but actually the rendering and the way you search things in said state.

If I were you I would invest time in 2 things:

1. **debounce** for the searching

**debounce** doesn't trigger the search immediately but "waits" a set amount of time for the user to stop typing and then it triggers the function.

Here's an example in React:

```
// you can use another one. I've just used this one before and it works
import debounce from "throttle-debounce";

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // "waits" for 750 ms
        this.search = debounce(this.search, 750);
    }

    search() { ... }

    render() {
      <input type="text" onKeyUp={this.search} />
    }
}
```

2. If you have a big list then [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is a good bet. You can use [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) for that.

> React components for efficiently rendering large lists and tabular
>   data

You can even access the List demo [here](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List)

3. A good UI design and pagination

react-virtualized **List** component will only render what is being seen by the user. So if you have a nice UI design you can juice up a lot of performance from a really big list of values.

Many times it comes down to how you display data to your end-users. So you can add pagination to your data and fetch more either with pagination links or a infinite scroll feature.

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time.

The problem I had was with constant setStating of the component state which was with a big list too much of a burden. I tried to negate the problem by setting the filtered list inside a reducer and that proved to be much faster. Also since that wasn't snappy enough instead of mutating the filtered list I created another list with ids for the shown items which I used to set hidden css-classes for filtered items.

I'll take a look at the react-virtualized at some point but for now I'll focus on something else. Here's the site btw. https://kurssim.me